# Turning second data into numbers

Tags: r, date, milliseconds

I have a data set with millisecond data, and I used the following code to convert it to a date/time:

```
> cl1$date <- strptime(cl1[,1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
> head(cl1$date)

[1] "2012-06-06 10:30:00.4" "2012-06-06 10:30:00.5" "2012-06-06 10:30:00.6"
[4] "2012-06-06 10:30:00.7" "2012-06-06 10:30:00.8" "2012-06-06 10:30:00.9"
...    
[71935] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.28" "2012-06-27 10:59:55.38" "2012-06-27 10:59:55.48"
[71938] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.58" "2012-06-27 10:59:55.68" "2012-06-27 10:59:55.78"
```

But now i want to transfer them from `"2012-06-27 10:59:55.28"` to `"2012-06-27 10:59:55.3"` (i.e. only 1 decimal for millisecond). What should I do to modify it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ttt<-as.POSIXlt("2012-06-27 10:59:55.28")

options(digits.secs=1)
ttt
[1] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.2"

options(digits.secs=2)
ttt
[1] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.28"

ttt$sec<-round(ttt$sec,1)
ttt
[1] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.3"

as.character(ttt)
[1] "2012-06-27 10:59:55.3"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks and this is very helpful. And I also tried to only use as.POSIXlt and it works, I just got confused that does that mean strptime here is not working? or what's the difference between them?

Comment: `strptime`should work. However, you only need it, if you need to specify a non-standard datetime format. For the standard format `as.POSIXlt` is sufficient.